# Add various Fields in a Sharepoint List Programmatically

Tags: list, development

i need a method where add various Fields in a Sharepoint List, but these Fields must be in the parameter of this method.

Show me this method and how should I use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this to get you going perhaps?

```
 private static void AppendNewFieldToListIfNonExistsent(SPList list, string internalName,
    string displayName, SPFieldType fieldType, Guid? lookupListId = null)
{
    if (list.Fields.ContainsField(internalName)) return;
    if (fieldType == SPFieldType.Lookup)
    {
        list.Fields.AddLookup(internalName, lookupListId.Value, false);
    }
    else
    {
        list.Fields.Add(internalName, fieldType, false);
    }
    var field = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(internalName);
    field.Title = displayName;
    field.Update();
    var view = list.DefaultView;
    if (view.ViewFields.Exists(field.InternalName)) return;
    view.ViewFields.Add(field.InternalName);
    view.Update();
}
```

[MSDN SPFIeldCollection.Add(SPField)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470667.aspx)
[MSDN SPFieldCollection.Add(String, SPFieldType, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472869.aspx)
[MSDN SPFieldCollection.AddLookup Method (String,Guid,Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436747.aspx)
[MSDN SPFieldCollection.AddLookup Method (String,Guid,Guid,Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms430950.aspx)

Comment: Tks Man!!!

But if this method uses a dictionary as a parameter passing the SPFields.

Comment: Your method? In that case just loop through them. You could add SPField directly, but it's a bit odd I think because of the SPField constructors

Comment: What is the defintion of EnsureLookupEntities? It appears to be a custom method

Comment: @vandre I think it was meant as a helper method which would create the field on the lookup list if non-existing, I didn't include the method (with body) as I didn't find it important. Removed for now. Note that `lookupListId` can be null here, so a `Debug.Assert(lookupListId != null, "lookupListId != null");` could be smart to use. Also, one can do `switch` on `fieldType` if necessary. (Since I removed `EnsureLookupEntities` I also removed SPWeb and LookupField, although field could be used to point to specific field)